# UILocalNotification not called when is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm try to fire UILocalNotification when app is in background and is in active state. I use following:

In App Delegate i want to "catch" notification callback by this (it's not called):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo{

    NSLog(@"recieve-old-notif-here");

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{


    NSLog(@"recieve-old-notif");
}
```

Here is how i declared local notification:

```
NSString *strToShow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Время вставать"];


UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];

notification.alertBody = strToShow;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Please note that i already achieve that task with iOS 10 notifications, but i want to support this feature on older version devices.

So, my delegate methods suppose to call but their does not, why?

Comment: Delegates are supposed to call when your App is in Foreground, not Background.

Comment: hi, are you registering for `UILocalNotification` ???????????????

Comment: @iphonic what is difference?

Comment: Is the local notification generated from a Background fetch ?

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj no, that is all of my code

Comment: @SeanLintern88 i present all code i used above, thats all

Comment: When the app is in Background, you will get Notification in the device, on tapping the Notification the delegates methods are called, when you are in Foreground device won't show you notification, but will call the delegate automatically so you can choose to show your custom alert.

Comment: Do you know the difference between Remote and Local notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in delegate :

## ifdef __IPHONE_8_0

```
//Right, that is the point
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

## else

```
//register to receive notifications
UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
```

## endif

and below delegate methods;

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif
```